# Vuejs and laravel authentication

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js and want to use it with laravel. I want to convert laravel's built in authentication to Vue.js components. Please provide suggestions from where should I start or any tutorial link.

Comment: you can use vuejs separately from laravel and authenticate using laravel passport. there is a package called apilaravue which has implemented this already: https://github.com/apilaravue/apilaravue

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior but i want to use in laravel's inbuilt implementation.

Comment: Then use it with blade

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior then can i use my vue components inside blade files.

Comment: maybe, just try it